# How to use a github repository

Tags: html, github

I have downloaded a Github zip file and loaded the contents of the file into my web server. When I run the index.html file, the file loads but the functionality I want (in this case, recording video) does not work. Is there something basic that I am missing? The link to the code I downloaded is: https://github.com/nusofthq/Media-Recorder-API-Demo

Comment: `inspect element` and check what kind of error you are getting in the `console`.

Comment: Thank you! The console led me to a document that told me that I had to either run the file through localhost or to put the file onto a server with https rather than http. The github files now work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

See the note added to the the comment from Adhinay.